# How to access to second language on Google Play store

Tags: google-play

I have uploaded my first app to Google Play store. The primary language was English, secondary Slovenian. But now I can only access Slovenian version.

How can I access and get link for English version?

Comment: Please use add a comment link under Nick's answer to reply Nick's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about the app description in the Play store, or the languages in the app itself.

- If you are talking about the languages in the app itself, there aren't two different versions. The app is the same. To see the English strings, you just change the language on your device to English, to see the Slovenian strings you change the language on the device to slovenian. But both sets of strings are in the App.
- this is made slightly more complicated if you use an [App Bundle]https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/(). This reduces download size for users by only downloading the languages that the device supports. If a new language is added to the device, then a new split APK with the new strings will be downloaded automatically by Play
- if you are talking about the language for the store listing in the Google Play store, then you need to change your language either on the device, or in the web browser you are visiting the store in.